# Ubuntu 18.04 performed "apt-get upgrade". Now, Slow Computer -- Graphics card Hardware Driver Update?

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors

Current Solution: I could only solve my issue by not performing an Ubuntu 18.04.4 upgrade or run Software Updater to upgrade 18.04.4.

I'm new to Ubuntu but I come from a strong background in MS Windows so I know how to navigate display drivers, etc from this platform but not strong, yet, with Ubuntu, hence my question.

Using newly installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS for the past week and performed my weekly "apt update/upgrade" yesterday.

My desk setup has been 2 external monitors (connected via DisplayPort and HDMI) with laptop lid closed both for my Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.

After the Ubuntu 18.04.4 update yesterday, now, if I close my laptop lid, my computer slows do to the point I can't even run a youtube video, though it still is functioning.
So it is not a suspension of function, as could happen if the "Suspend when lid closed" was enabled in my Power Settings.  It is an excruciating reduction in function to where it takes my cursor 2 seconds to move across my 27" monitor.

If I leave the laptop lid open, the performance is perfect but my desk setup can't handle the laptop being opened.

1. In Tweaks, Power Suspend is disabled "when laptop lid is closed
2. In Settings, "Suspend & Power Button", Automatic Suspend is OFF.
3. I rebooted 5 times.

Do I need to update the hardware driver for my graphics card due to the update that has now, apparently, a discrepancy?
Does "apt-get upgrade" even "touch" the hardware drivers?

Thanks,
klieber

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Also try this

```
sudo dpkg --configure *
```

Comment: HI, I tried the "sudo apt autoremove" and rebooted.  This did not correct the problem.  i then tried your 2nd suggetion, "sudo dpkg --configure *" and got reported errors for everything this command tried, i.e. Errors were encountered while processing: desktop, documents,...etc, videos....

Comment: this command is used to detect and remove error your ubuntu firmware is highly damaged i suggest to backup data and reinstall and also send your laptop ram specs

Comment: Hi Source Code, I have 64GB of RAM

Comment: Hi Source Code, Can you guide me a bit more.  Who do I send my laptop RAM specifications to? Do I post it within my question? I haven't yet re-installed because I'm trying to understand a bit more how you know my firmware is damaged.

Comment: i have done some research it happend if some core libs during updates are not installed correctly there is a way to fix your issue there is an app named time shift  download it , it is backup from it backup ur data and then reinstall 20.04 cause it is most maintained version  after install of 20.04 install timeshift on it plug your usb on which you backup data using timeshift and click restore your problem is solved

Comment: Hi Source Code,I just completed removing and reinstalling a new, checksum tested Ubuntu 18.04.4. Closing my laptop lid worked fine until I did an update. Once again, when I close my laptop monitor lid my computer stops working. So reinstalling a clean 18.04 did not work.  btw, I can't use 20.04 yet until Ettus UHD and GNuRadio source can be built on this version.

Comment: After the update, I ran "sudo apt autoremove" and the response was :::: klieb@Ubun18Dell7730:~$ sudo apt autoremove
[sudo] password for klieb: 
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Comment: I then ran "sudo dpkg --configure -a" I got::::::Setting up man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Updating database of manual pages ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20190110~18.04.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libgtk2.0-0:amd64 (2.24.32-1ubuntu1) ...

Comment: Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.9) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-61-genericI: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme1n1p4
I: (UUID=c7cd4a52-b22d-4c9c-b1b3-f66c674a93eb)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.

Comment: Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.41) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...